# aws Route53: Register domain name for 1 year

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, domain-name

I am trying to register a .com.au domain name for one year, but can't seem to, only 2 years.

[image: Route 53 domain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Domains That You Can Register with Amazon Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/registrar-tld-list.html#com.au) documentation page:

> **.com.au (Australia)**
>
> **Registration and renewal period:** Two years

So, the price is quote *per year*, but you will need to purchase for *two years*. This is a requirement of the **.com.au** registrar.